# Cassandra "compactionstats" and "garbagecollect"

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 nodes in my cluster.
I've run the command:

```
nodetool garbagecollect my_schema my_table
```

on one node. When I check on the other two nodes the command:

```
nodetool compactionstats
```

I get the result:

```
pending tasks: 1
- my_schema.my_table: 1
```

So, My question is, Does starting the garbagecollect on one node mean it will eventually run on the other nodes? Is that the reason I see the pending on the other two nodes or do I need to run the garbagecollect command on each nodes separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodetool subcommands are triggering the action on that node only, so you need to run `nodetool garbagecollect` on every node separately. It also depends on what do you want to remove - by default it deletes only partitions and rows, but not individual deleted cells. If you need to delete cells as well, use `-g CELL` flag (see this [blog post](https://intertubes.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/what-does-nodetool-garbagecollect-do-in-cassandra/) for more details).

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So I need to run the command on every node. Do you know why the other nodes show a "pending" task?

Comment: I just looked to source code - it triggers the compaction job on the node itself... Maybe you run a repair at the same time?

Comment: That pending message went await after awhile... I ran the same garbagecollect on other nodes. Thanks